# [NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecognised selector sent to instance in NSString comparision?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I got this error [**NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecognised selector sent to instance**

when I try to check NSString comparison

My code is:

```
if ([[[dict objectForKey:@"login"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **read** the error. It clearly states that the value for key `login` is (already) a string

```
if ([[dict objectForKey:@"login"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
{ 
}
```

or with more convenient key subscription syntax (available for many, many years)

```
if ([dic[@"login"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The object is already a string, so you don't need to use the `stringValue` selector:

```
if ([[dict objectForKey:@"login"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
{ 
}
```

Note: comparing this with `"1"` is dodgy; convert it to `NSNumber` if it's a number.